# Alternative to \large, \Large, \Huge, \small etc in ConTeXt

Tags: context

Are there simple alternative of these font sizes in ConTeXt? Or one needs to use some special module? I looked at this page [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definebodyfontenvironment). It seems to be a lot of boilerplate of such a simple task.

Comment: Yes, there exists some by default, see [the ConTeXt wiki about font switching](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Font_Switching).

Comment: You can change font sizes with `\tfa`, `\tfb`, `\tfc`, etc. or e.g. with `\setupdodyfont[18pt]`. If that doesn't suit your needs please add more details and explain what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @Marco Thanks. This almost does what I want. You can add this as answer. Some newbie like me would be able to search it easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the font size for the entire text using
[\setupbodyfont](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupbodyfont):

```
\setupbodyfont [18pt]
```

If you want to change the font size of a smaller part of the text
you can use the following constructs:

```
{\tfa large}
{\tfb even larger}
{\tfc huge}
```

Or if you prefer absolute values:

```
\switchtobodyfont [16pt]
```

For more details see the [ConTeXt wiki - Font switching → Font sizes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Font_Switching#Font_sizes).